# Conditions in terraform cdktf python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-cdk

I am trying to experiment with terraform cdktf python :
my mission consists  of how really condition is working with cdktf.
So i tried to create  outputs based on variable values and  it seems like the condition always  return false  here is an example :

```
    if test.string_value=="TNTN":
        TerraformOutput(self, "alb_dns",
                    value=web_server_alb.dns_name
                    )
        TerraformOutput(self, "instance_id",
                    value=instance_type

                    )
        TerraformOutput(self, "test", value=test)
```

And i'm expecting that alb_dns, instance_type  and product is outputted when the condition is true.
Note that test variable is  passed throw env variables (TF_VAR_test=TNTN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDKTF does not provide any values of e.g. resources at runtime, but instead uses [Tokens](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/tokens). Therefore you can not build conditionals on runtime values, you can only have conditionals on things known at compile time.